# How to create a Tagged Value Types object by scripting

Tags: javascript, object, tags

I'm trying to create a set of scripts to manipulate tagged value Types:
addTV_Type
deleteTV_Type
renameTV_Type
getTV_Type

The first 3 are no problem but the last one is a pain in the ass. First guess was to use Repository.Propertytypes.GetByName(). Unfortunately that doesn't work, the method doesn't return anything. Of course I can loop trough the collection. And that actually works but my first attempt was using SQL to get the values required for the Tagged Value Type (which actualy is a EA.Propertytype object). And her I got into trouble, how do I create an EA.Propertytype object and fill its properties?

```
var TVT as EA.Propertytype;
TVT.Tag = "something";
```

doesn't work. What am I doing wrong

The first 3 functions are as follow

```
function renameTV_Type(tagNaam, newTagNaam)
{
    let sql = formatString("UPDATE t_propertytypes SET property = '{1}' WHERE property = '{0}';",[tagNaam, newTagNaam]);
    let xmlQueryResult = Repository.SQLQuery(sql);
    Repository.Propertytypes.Refresh();
}

function deleteTV_Type(tagNaam)
{
    let sql = formatString("DELETE FROM t_propertytypes WHERE property = '{0}';",[tagNaam]);
    let xmlQueryResult = Repository.SQLQuery(sql);
    Repository.Propertytypes.Refresh();
}

function addTV_Type(tagNaam, description, notes)
{
    let sql = formatString("INSERT INTO t_propertytypes (property, description, notes) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}');",[tagNaam, description, notes]);
    let xmlQueryResult = Repository.SQLQuery(sql);
    Repository.Propertytypes.Refresh();
}
```

Adding a new type works but only if the type does not exist

Comment: What is `var TVT as EA.Propertytype;` supposed to mean?

Comment: What is a "tagged value type"? What is `EA.Propertytype`? What is `Repository`? What is your database schema?